# How does this flutter application code work?

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax

I was trying to understand a code of a flutter app, it simply creates a list nd generate 999 element for the list, i just couldn't exactly understad how the generation code works.

```
final items = List<Listitem>.generate(
1000,
(i) => i % 6 == 0
    ? Headingitem('heading $i')
    : Messageitem('sender $i', 'message body $i'));
```

i also couldn't understand the key widgets, i read that they work as an identifier for widgets so if a new widget tried to change an element, it must have the same key as the old widget, but the syntax is really confusing, for example why adding super (key: key) in the code?

```
const App({Key? key, required this.items}) : super(key: key);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 final items = List<Listitem>.generate(
```

We are going to create a List of ListItems by using a generator (code loop)

```
1000,
```

Our generator loop is going to run 1000 loops

```
(i) =>
```

Our function that will run 1000 times will be given the iteration number as an argument named "i"

```
 i % 6 == 0
    ? Headingitem('heading $i')
    : Messageitem('sender $i', 'message body $i'));
```

This uses a ternary:  `(boolean condition) ? (if true, this) : (if false, this);`  You can think of this sort of like:

```
if (i % 6 == 0) {
  Headingitem('heading $i')
} else {
  Messageitem('sender $i', 'message body $i'));
}
```

First we check for every 6th loop: `i % 6` The '%' is the modulo operator and will return the remainder of i dividied by 6. If i/6 == remainder 0 then create a `Headingitem()`, if not create a `Messageitem()`

So for items (i) 0,6,12,18,... we create a `Headingitem()`, and for all the other items we create a `Messageitem()`

---

**Keys** If you assign a unique key for a widget you can find that widget in the widget tree. You don't have to give a widget a key- it's an optional parameter. If you give a widget a unique key with `key: keyvalue` you can find that widget with `find.byKey(keyvalue)`. An example of where this is used: if you want to access members or methods of a Widget that aren't exposed in the constructor, or outside a widget's build() function, you can use the key to find it and access it's members and methods.